# Can zlib inflate read large gunzipped files?

Tags: c, zlib

This is the latest version of my code.Thanks to your zpipe.c, it works fine now for all my gunzipped files regardless of their sizes. But the thing I do not understand is that in inner loop printf("%s", out) still prints same initial results(the part decompressed in the first cycle).But in decompressed file file.txt, everything is OK.Everything is decompressed normal. I have to process decompressed outputs in every inner cycle and actually I do not need output file(file.txt).

```
while (1) {
    int bytes_read;

    bytes_read = fread (in, sizeof (char), sizeof (in), file);
    printf("hello");
    FAIL (ferror (file), "read");
    strm.avail_in = bytes_read;
    printf("%i\n",bytes_read);
    getchar();
    if (strm.avail_in==0)
        break;
    strm.next_in=in;
    do {
        strm.avail_out = CHUNK;
        strm.next_out=out;
        CALL_ZLIB(inflate (&strm, Z_NO_FLUSH));

        printf ("%s", out);

        getchar();
        have=CHUNK-strm.avail_out;
        fwrite(out,1,have,f2);     
    } while (strm.avail_out == 0);
    if (feof (file))
    {
        inflateEnd (& strm);
        break;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you Mark. So basically you want me add strm.next_out=CHUNK; strm.next_in=strm.avail_in; after inflate() in inner loop?

Comment: The code as it now stands will have a memory leak in some cases.  If the size of the input is an exact multiple of `sizeof(in)`, then after all of that input is read and inflated, the `feof(file)` will _not_ detect end of file, since you haven't yet tried to read past the end.  You should do the `inflateEnd()` after the main loop exits.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not resetting `next_in` and `next_out` in your loop.  Those are advanced past what is read and what is written.  Please read [zlib.h](http://zlib.net/manual.html) and then look at [how to use zlib](http://zlib.net/zlib_how.html).

Comment: +1, though that `do... while (strm.avail_out == 0);` comes directly from the [example](http://zlib.net/zpipe.c) (Which I realise you're the author of. Just to clarify, I don't mean the loop's contents.)

Comment: Ah, the indenting misled me -- I missed the `do`.  The `while` should be on the same line as the `}`.

Comment: Thank you Mark. So basically you want me add strm.next_out=CHUNK; strm.next_in=strm.avail_in; after inflate() in inner loop?

Comment: No.  Setting pointers to integers would result in a crash.  They would be set to what you set them to in the first place, `out` and `in`.  `next_in` would be set at the same time as `avail_in`.  `next_out` would be set at the same time as `avail_out`.  Please read the documentation.

Comment: The thing still I do not understand is that how fread can read all my 3 106 153 bytes on one try(I printed bytes_read), though there are parameters like sizeof(char) sizeof(in).My expectation was sizeof(char)*sizeof(in)=1*CHUNK=1*550 000=550 000bytes.Can I assume C compiler extended my in to in[3 106 153] char array though I  declared it as in[550 000]? I tried to reset next_out by putting next_out=next_out+CHUNK after inflate in inner loop. No success.

Comment: The problem is that I am having trouble to know what is read and what was written in the first cycle of inner loop, because I am not sure in the CHUNK's role in the program.Thank you.

Comment: I recommend that you start with [zpipe.c](http://www.zlib.net/zpipe.c), and go from there.

Comment: On top,I put the latest version of my code.Thanks to your zpipe.c, it works fine now for all my gunzipped files regardless of their sizes. But the thing I do not understand is that in inner loop printf("%s", out) still prints same initial results(the part decompressed in the first cycle).But in decompressed file file.txt, everything is OK.Everything is decompressed normal. I have to process decompressed outputs in every inner cycle and actually I do not need output file(file.txt).

Comment: I understood it. Because the second cycle of inner loop decompressed less bytes, so I just see end of the first cycle results since out is owerwritten on every cycle of inner loop.Can you explain me how can C compiler (is it C compiler?) store 5 570 560 chars in out[550 000]? I would like to know the reason before I proceed further. Thank you.

Comment: You answered your own question.  `out[]` is overwritten in each inner loop.

Comment: Can you explain me how can C compiler (is it C compiler?) store 5 570 560 chars in out[550 000]? I would like to know the reason before I proceed further. Thank you.